# Eclipse java editor: format code

Tags: java, eclipse, format, editor

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600
```

Eclipse formatting code does not work for source code containing the following case:

```
String foo = (bar!=null)? value1 : 
        value2;
System.out.println("hello world");
```

the value1 and value2 can be very long, so split into two lines.

Java editor: format the code above (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>), and get the following result:

```
String foo = (bar!=null)? value1 : 
        value2;
        System.out.println("hello world");
```

Source code can be very big, and it is convenient to select all and then press (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) to format the whole code. Is there a way to avoid the formatting error above?  Thanks.

Comment: Hm, make value1 and value2 small by making them methods perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use single line comments `//` to force the eclipse code formatter (and other code formatters) to preserve the line(s) you want. Something like

```
String foo = (bar != null) ? //
        value1 : //
        value2;
System.out.println("hello world");
```

Comment: Yes, I've done a similar thing today with an enum that I've created, to try to prevent bad formatting.

Comment: @Dave I formatted the code in this post with eclipse Mars.2

Comment: What is your specific minor version and build id? Thanks

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600